# NetSuite Transactions extract to SQL Database

Tags: database, netsuite, data-migration

what tool do you use to extract NetSuite transactions, we have transactions from 2013 - 2017 and we are going to migrate to a new environment, how can we secure our transactions into a SQL DB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Netsuite's ODBC connect plugin to copy your data to any relational DB. It does have limitation. For this you will need to subscribe to pricey SuiteAnalytic Connect module.
https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8184

One of the best tool is from Sesame Software's Data warehousing tool

http://sesamesoftware.com/relational-junction/netsuite-backup/

This one is really flexible.I have used both I like the later one.